# Embedding Rekall in an external python program

Tags: python-2.7

http://docs.rekall.googlecode.com/git/tutorial.html#_embedding_rekall_in_an_external_python_program

I try to run the program as the link suggested, however i am getting this error

> "ValueError: Unable to load profile WinXPSP2x86 from any repository."

look like it does not automatically search for *Profile* like running commands

this should be the old codes, as `WinXPSP3` is not a valid profile name, so with the suggestion from the author, I am looking into

https://code.google.com/p/grr/source/browse/client/client_actions/grr_rekall.py#157

but i am new to it, need some help to make it work

e.g. import an image, and call pslist

any ideas? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are just following an old link that is not accessible anyway.

http://www.rekall-forensic.com/docs/Manual/tutorial.html

The example found here works well !